# Embed SQL Data into Excel Table

Tags: sql, vba, excel, oracle11g

I have an Oracle DB connection that pulls data from the DB into Excel. My only issue is that I want it pulled into a table rather than just dump the data into a sheet. My PivotTable needs to be refreshed based on the Table updating. This is my sample code that works. Is there a property for the QueryTables object that embeds the data into a table?

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(connection),Destination:=Range("A1"))

 .Sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
 .FieldNames = True
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841237.aspx) with the Query Table. Below is an example with a MySQL connection.

```
Dim constr As String

constr = "ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};server=localhost;_
          database=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, _
          Source:=constr, _
          Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `Table`"
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "TableName"  
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```